# ionic 2/3 - native linkedin - not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, linkedin-api

I am using linkedin native plugin in ionic 2.
this is what I did:

1. created a new app on linkedin.
2. Under the mobile section, pasted package name from config.xml file and then generated hash using the following command:
   keytool -exportcert -alias ALIAS_HERE -keystore path/to/mykey.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
   and pasted the hash in the package hash.
   now when I am trying to login, it's not firing up at all.
   getActiveSession is working but not the login.
   can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is this working now? If it is not can you put your code for the `login()` method?

Comment: did you find a solution ? I have the same issue

Comment: Yeah, you need to have the linkedin app installed otherwise use auth0 or you can just follow linkedin doc for oAuth 2.0 for which you need to install in-app browser in your project.
Link to doc:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#